# Read Only Details (Employee ID) from test file and transfer to excel sheet

Tags: python, spyder

I have text file containing employee details and various other details. Below is the consolidated data  as shown below.

```
Data file created on 4 Jun 2020
GROUPCASEINSENSITIVE ON
#KCT-User-Group 
GROUP KCT  ALopp190 e190 ARaga789 Lshastri921
GROUP KCT  DPatel592 ANaidu026 e026  KRam161 e161 
#KBN-User-Group
GROUP KBN  SPatil322 e322 LAgarwal908 AKeshri132 e132 
GROUP KBN  BRaju105 e105 LNaik110 PNeema163 e163 
#PDA-User-Group
GROUP PDA  SRoy977 AAgarwal594 e594 AMath577 e577 
GROUP PDA  BSharma865 e865 CUmesh195 RRana354
```

When i run a Python code i need output as shown below

```
ALopp190 
ARaga789 
Lshastri921
DPatel592 
ANaidu026
KRam161
SPatil322 
LAgarwal908 
AKeshri132
BRaju105
LNaik110 
PNeema163
SRoy977 
AAgarwal594
AMath577
BSharma865
CUmesh195 
RRana354
```

From that text file i need only the above data.This is what i had tried but its not working

```
def user(li):
    n = len (li)
    for j in range(0, n, 2):
        print (li[j])
import os
os.getcwd()
fo = open(r'C:\\Users\\Kiran\\Desktop\\Emplyoees\\User.txt', 'r')
for i in fo.readlines():
    li = list(i.split(" "))
    #print (li)
    li.remove("GROUP")
    li.remove("KCT")
    li.remove("KBN")
    li.remove("PDA")
    user (li)
```

I am new to python and not sure how to get the data. Can you please assist me in fixing this issue.

Comment: Are expected output words always contain letters+digits?

Comment: does the file contain comments and first two lines?

Comment: @Alderven Yes the output contains only letters+digits

Comment: @komatiraju032 Yes it contains

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    res = []
    for line in fp.readlines()[2:]:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            res += [x for x in line.split()[2:] if not (x.startswith('e') and x.replace('e', '').isnumeric())]

print('\n'.join(res))
```

**Output:**

```
ALopp190
ARaga789
Lshastri921
DPatel592
ANaidu026
KRam161
SPatil322
LAgarwal908
AKeshri132
BRaju105
LNaik110
PNeema163
SRoy977
AAgarwal594
AMath577
BSharma865
CUmesh195
RRana354
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, Its working fine. Is there a way where i can get the output directly to excel sheet via code only.

Comment: this will help https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/

Answer (score 0):

Based on output format (string + digit) you can parse it with `regex` and then use `pandas` to save results to excel:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = re.findall('[A-Z]\w+\d+', f.read())

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.to_excel('result.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, Its working fine. Is there a way where i can get the output directly to excel sheet via code only